# shell script for creating multiple image files ascending order

Tags: shell, for-loop, scripting

so the thing is, I'm trying to code a shell script that creates multiple image files in an ascending order, but, the ones with only one digit must come with a zero first. I'm a beginner and searching throughout the internet I've found that there are some syntax differences when it comes to the indexing system, so on my computer the following "for" syntax works fine, but I'm sure there's a better approach to that. there it goes:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
  do
    if (${i:0:1} == "0") then
      touch "0${i}.jpg"
    else
      touch "$i.jpg"
    fi
  done
```

it returns "bad substitution". is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: Don't wrap `()` around the `if` condition. Use `if [ ${i:0:1} = 0 ]; then`. But you can also just put the leading zeros in the for list directly and/or use `printf '%02d' $i` to get formatted numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {0..15}; do printf -v name "%02i.jpg" $i; touch "$name" ; done
```

Or, if it is easier to read:

```
for i in {0..15}; do 
    printf -v name "%02i.jpg" $i
    touch "$name"
done
```

When this is done, the following files are created:

```
$ ls
00.jpg  01.jpg  02.jpg  03.jpg  04.jpg  05.jpg  06.jpg  07.jpg  08.jpg  09.jpg  10.jpg  11.jpg  12.jpg  13.jpg  14.jpg  15.jpg
```

#### Explanation

- `for i in {0..15}; do`

  This starts the loop.
- `printf -v name "%02i.jpg" $i`

  This creates a shell variable `name` which has the desired format.  `%02i` instructs `printf` to write the number out in two space with zero-padding.
- `touch "$name"`

  This creates the file
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

#### Alternative

Starting from the script in the question, a couple changes are needed on the `if` statement.  The following works:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
do
    if [ "$i" -le 9 ]; then
      touch "0${i}.jpg"
    else
      touch "$i.jpg"
    fi
done
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! but it still does not work here, though. when I run "sh sc.sh" it reports:

sc.sh: 2: printf: Illegal option -v
touch: cannot touch ‘’: No such file or directory

Comment: @flpost Please try `bash sc.sh`.  If that doesn't work, please tell me what OS you are on and, if you know, what shell is your default shell.

Comment: @flpost Also, would you quote the complete line 2 of `sc.sh` as you have it?

Comment: @flpost Another possibility is to try the revised version of your code that is in the updated answer.  It avoids `printf` entirely.

Comment: running "bash sc.sh" still won't work. I'm using Mint 17 and my default shell is "/bin/bash". apparently, when I put parenthesis instead of brackets, it accepts it.